# Deployed solution using stsadm commands..But it is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, stsadm

I have a differnt issue, that i was deployed the solution using stsadm commands. feature is showing site collection solutions and it is activated. But the functionality for the solution is not working. Deployed same solution by using VS 2010. At that time it is working as expected. Changed the scope of the feature from site to farm. At that time also staadm solution is not working..VS deployed is working as expected.

Can any one pls guide me on this....

Regards,
Suresh.

Comment: If I understood correctly, after you deployed the wsp as a farm solution, you still see the feature in the Site Collection Features list? And what is you solution supposed to do? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I was deployed the solution in farm level solution is showing at farm level solutions. But the functionality is not working. Also changed the scope to Site collection level not worked.